# axios request Error: write EPROTO 140378279196608:error:14094458:SSL

Tags: axios, openssl

I have been trying to call some payment integration endpoint with Axios and getting this error

"Error: write EPROTO 139867624232896:error:14094458:SSL
routines:ssl3_read_bytes:tlsv1 unrecognized
name:../deps/openssl/openssl/ssl/record/rec_layer_s3.c:1546:SSL alert number 112"

I have tried it also with node-fetch package getting the same error but it works with curl command. I didn't use any proxy.
the sample code I have tried is

try {

```
let result = await axios.get(
  "https://api.chapa.dev/v1/transaction/verify/" + req.query.tx_ref,
  {
    headers: {
      Authorization: "Bearer " + CHAPA_SECRET_KEY,
    },
  }
);

console.log("Result: " + result.data);
//TODO: save result
```

} catch (error) {

```
console.log("something happened " + error);
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured it out I was using the wrong endpoint which I copied from Chapa's website Js sample code and the endpoint should be     https://api.chapa.co/v1/transaction/verify/tf_ref-some_ref
and the problem is solved